# PageListPaper Html helper throws an error "security critical type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' failed"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

View File Listed below

```
     @using PagedList;
        @using PagedList.Mvc;


        @model IPagedList<MVCDemo.Models.Employee>
       <table> 
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Gender)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Email)
        </th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
   </table> 

       @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, searchBy = Request.QueryString["searchBy"], search = Request.QueryString["search"] }))
```

Controller action method Shows here

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search, int? page)
{
    if (searchBy == "Gender")
    {
        return View(db.Employees.Where(x => x.Gender == search || search == null).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 3));
    }
    else
    {
        return View(db.Employees.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 3));
    }
}
```

When I using above code following error throws

> Additional information: Attempt by security transparent method
>   'PagedList.Mvc.HtmlHelper.PagedListPager(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   PagedList.IPagedList, System.Func`2)' to access
>   security critical type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' failed.
>
> Assembly 'PagedList.Mvc, Version=3.18.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=abbb863e9397c5e1' is marked with the
>   AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security
>   transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in
>   AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent
>   by default, which may be the cause of this exception.

Expecting a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install Latest PagedList.Mvc version 4.5.0, and If you installed PagedList.MVC it Automatically update your PagedList Version 1.15 to 1.17.0
Try Below Command

```
PM> Install-Package PagedList.Mvc
```